# Forge (Dedicated Server - Custom VPS) Stuck on 'Provisioning'

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-14.04, provisioning, dedicated-server, laravel-forge

I have a dedicated server and I have had a completely clean/fresh copy of Ubuntu 14.04 x64 installed on to it (without MySQL, PHP, Apache, Nginx etc) as required by Forge. I then run the command to provision the server provided by Forge while logged in as root via SSH.

The process appears to run and complete successfully but when I go to Forge it shows the server is stuck on 'Provisioning'.

I have tried this several times to no avail. I've refreshed my GitHub tokens and retried but no joy.

I never receive an email from Forge with my credentials and if I exit SSH I cannot log back in because of the changes made by Forge and I then have to contact the host to get them to fix the situation.

Does anyone have any idea what may be occurring here? I'm at a loss on what to do next.

I did spot this output while the provisioning process was being completed. Perhaps this has something to do with it:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini’: File exists
nginx: unrecognized service

npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.7

Setting up postgresql-contrib-9.4 (9.4.4-1.pgdg14.04+1) ...
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied
CREATE ROLE
 * Restarting PostgreSQL 9.4 database server                                                                                                                               [ OK ]
could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied

rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/nginx/sites-available/default’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default’: No such file or directory

ps-watcher won't be started/stopped unless it is configured
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar problem which led me to contact Forge support. This was the response I received:

> This typically means there was an error adding the server's SSH key to your GitHub / Bitbucket accounts. Try refreshing your tokens in your account profile -> "Authentication" tab. Make sure to refresh both source control providers if you have ever linked them to Forge. Once you have done that delete the hanging server and try provisioning a new one.

In my case, I had Forge linked to Github, as well as Bitbucket, but was only refreshing my Github token since that's what I was using for that particular server.

Hope this helps or at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, I have already refreshed the tokens for GitHub several times.

Comment: Have you tried a complete reset? Delete the hanging server >> Revoke Forge's access from your Github's authorized applications >> Delete any Forge ssh keys from your Github >> _Then_ refresh the tokens >> Launch a new server.

Comment: No, I haven't tried that full process but I have it working now anyway. The host ran through the forge.sh script line by line and ran the commands. It turns out SSH was set to listen on port 2020 so there needed to be some configuration for Forge to gain access.